# Strange Ubuntu Error Message on WSL Windows 11

Tags: 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have just installed WSL for Windows 11. Getting this error Message

> <3>WSL (10) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2803: Failed to translate E:\app\Adnan\product\12.2.0\client_1[image]

Comment: The path shown seems to belong to an windows file. Contact Microsoft support

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9360